# How to combine logical operators with search filters in python LDAP?

Tags: python, python-2.7, search, ldap, python-ldap

I am a newbie at python and I am working on a personal project of mine. The project includes grabbing data through LDAP, which returns JSON data. 
Sample of data:

```
cn=abcd
[[('uid=abcd,OU=active,OU=employees,OU=people,O=xxxx.com', 
{'status': ['Active'], 
'co': ['India'], 
'cn': ['abcd'], 
'msDS-UserAccountDisabled': ['FALSE'], 
'departmentNumber': ['122839'],
'objectClass': ['top', 'person', 'organizationalPerson', 'user', 'inetOrgPerson',    `'ciscoperson'], 'userPrincipalName': ['surahuja'], 'publishpager': ['n'],`
```

Let's say that the content of the data is something like

```
 'directreportees' : ['2345','1234','6789']
```

Right now,the search filter is something like

```
for item in directreportees:
   search_filter = "(employeenumber=" + item +")"
```

I need to put the search filter in a form where I can specify that the no of direct reportees > 0. Is it possible through search filters ? or do I have no option but to grab data and perform test on it ?

Secondly, I need to search the department too. For eg, I need to check if the JSON value such as A.B.NOS. C contains a specific sequence such as NOS. Can I provide this check in the search filter too ?

Comment: _"The project includes grabbing data through LDAP, which returns JSON data."_ which LDAP is this? Are you sure you are not confusing _string representation_ of the response (which is in [`LDIF`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LDIF) format) with JSON?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid, I have placed a sample of the data. Is it JSON or LDIF,since I seem to be confused here.